# Why is the suite bar top styling messed up?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have SP 2013 Online and I noticed that the top bar style was modified (it's larger/taller than normal). I'm the only one with access to this particular site collection and I never made any changes so this is confusing me. I went to other site collections (even ones with no customization at all) and they are all affected.

Was this something caused by MS? -not sure how their updates are pushed out.

The element id with the issue is: "suiteBarTop"

[image]

Comment: Could we see a screenshot? Is it possible some global CSS is conflicting with the elements?

Comment: Where would the global CSS have been modified? Can I prevent this from being modified by other system admins?

Comment: I was just thinking if there is anything custom you may have written that could have targeted all div elements to be larger... I'd really need to see it to compare to the norm

Comment: Nope. I've never modified the global CSS and never noticed this change since making previous edits. Added an image, hope that helps.

Comment: I would recommend to open a support ticket with O365 team, they have better tools and control on the environment. they may help you.

Comment: It's a Microsoft update. There's nothing you can do about it. It's happening for everyone.

Comment: It's not just you we've seen it on our O365 environment and at least one of our clients. The client opened a MS ticket and MS confirmed that they had made changes to the "Office 365 Top Navigation Bar".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft is continuously improving Office 365 SharePoint Online. Most of the changes are somewhat announced and documented somewhere.

For example, this SharePoint Blog post mentions a few improvements recently made and rolled out (or at least are in progress to roll out):

http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/01/sharepoint-online-simplifies-admin-interface-plus-adds-new-controls-user-experience/

Obviously, the issue you are facing appears to be a new feature which is according to Microsoft under development but not yet rolled out.

For an official list of Office 365 features, you might want to check the Office 365 Roadmap page:

https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-365-roadmap-FX104343353.aspx

It looks like the change you are seeing is listed under "IN DEVELOPMENT" as "Custom Themes", which shows a screen capture with the profile picture instead of the user display name on the top right of the suite bar.